# Failed to reuse variable in C

Tags: c

I'm trying to code a program that can tell apart real and fake credit card numbers using Luhn's algorithm in C, which is

1. Multiply every other digit by 2, starting with the number’s
   second-to-last digit, and then add those products’ digits together.
2. Add the sum to the sum of the digits that weren’t multiplied by 2.
3. If the total’s last digit is 0 (or, put more formally, if the total
   modulo 10 is congruent to 0), the number is valid!

Then I coded something like this (I already declared all the functions at the top and included all the necessary libraries)

```
//Luhn's Algorithm
int luhn(long z)
{
    int c;
    return c = (sumall(z)-sumodd(z)) * 2 + sumaodd(z);
}


//sum of digits in odd position starting from the end
int sumodd(long x)
{
    int a;
    while(x)
    {
        a = a + x % 10;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return a;
}

//sum of all digits
int sumall(long y)
{
    int b;
    while(y)
    {
        b = b + y % 10;
        y /= 10;
    }
    return b;
}
```

But somehow it always gives out the wrong answer even though there's no error or bug detected. I came to notice that it works fine when my variable z stands alone, but when it's used multiple times in the same line of code with different functions, their values get messed up (in function luhn). I'm writing this to ask for any fix I can make to make my code run correctly as I intended.

I'd appreciate any help as I'm very new to this, and I'm not a native English speaker so I may have messed up some technical terms, but I hope you'd be able to understand my concerns.

Comment: Is this as simple as you haven't initialised your variables? Such as `int a=0;` C requires you to explicitly initialise local variables.

Comment: Use the compiler warnings: the `int a;` and the `int b;` have not been initialised. They have indeterminate values.

Comment: You may find this problem easier to solve if you represent your credit card number as a `char[]` instead of a `long`

Comment: Indeed no serious program confuses a digit string with an integer. It's a classic pitfall to think that a "number" has to be an integer. It's worse with phone "numbers" because you'll lose leading zeros, which are significant.

Comment: Have you run your code on a small number — maybe one with 6 digits, such as 987123 or perhaps 7 digits, such as 9876123.  You can print the values of 'sumall()` and `sumodd()` and so on.  I believe that you're supposed to ignore the 3 until you've worked on the rest of the digits, but AFAICS, you include it in both the `sumall()` and the `sumodd()` calculations.  Are you sure that's correct?

Comment: The `long` type is not required to be wider than 32 bit by ISO C. That means it might only be capable of storing 9 digit numbers (plus an extra digit that may only be 0, 1 or 2). Credit card numbers are 16 digits, typically, so you want `long long` that is required to be at least 64 bits wide.

Comment: "_even though there's no error or bug detected._":  Never be surprised that code that compiles contains bugs.  It is not the compiler's responsibility or capability to detect semantic errors.  Though elevating the warning level, and regarding them as errors can help.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comments. @Persixty @WeatherVane it wasn't about indeterminate values. When I use `sumodd` and `sumall` alone it worked just fine. The problem appeared in `luhn` when i try to reuse the z variable twice i believe. @WillisHershey @WeatherVane @Kaz the assignment required me to use `long` so it's impossible to change. @JonathanLeffler, I meant to use it so that in `luhn` i can subtract `sumodd` from `sumall` to find `sumeven`. I found it more difficult to code for `sumeven` so I only coded a function for all the digits and digits at odd positions.

Comment: @DanNguyen I promise it is about indeterminate values. You shouldn't have any problem reusing parameters like z. When you read variables that haven't been assigned all sorts of strange things might happen.  That's why it's call Unfefined Behaviour. Whatever you've got working works by coincidence.

Comment: @Persixty I actually did try to assign inital values to a and b but it didn't work

Comment: @DanNguyen Here's an example without initialisers that is broken https://ideone.com/hpQdlR and here's one with initialisers that works fine https://ideone.com/WyS5N3. I'm not sure what you did but your solution is working by accident (maybe stumbling on zeroes in the stack) whereas initialising the variables explicitly will always work. It simply doesn't make sense that you can't use `z` twice. That's just not how C works.

Answer (score 1):

`sumall` is wrong.

It should be `sumeven` from:

> Add the sum to the sum of the digits that **weren’t** multiplied by 2.

Your `sumall` is summing *all* digits instead of the non-odd (i.e. even) digits.

You should do the `* 2` *inside* `sumodd` as it should *not* be applied to the other [even] sum. And, it should be applied to the individual digits [vs the total sum].

---

Let's start with a proper definition from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Luhn_algorithm

The check digit is computed as follows:

1. If the number already contains the check digit, drop that digit to form the "payload." The check digit is most often the last digit.
2. With the payload, start from the rightmost digit. Moving left, double the value of every second digit (including the rightmost digit).
3. Sum the digits of the resulting value in each position (using the original value where a digit did not get doubled in the previous step).
4. The check digit is calculated by `10 − ( s mod ⁡ 10 )`

---

Note that if we have a credit card of `9x` where `x` is the check digit, then the payload is `9`.

The correct [odd] sum for that digit is: `9 * 2` --> `18` --> `1 + 8` --> `9`

But, `sumodd(9x) * 2` --> `9 * 2` --> `18`

---

Here's what I came up with:

```
// digsum -- calculate sum of digits
static inline int
digsum(int digcur)
{
    int sum = 0;

    for (;  digcur != 0;  digcur /= 10)
        sum += digcur % 10;

    return sum;
}

// luhn -- luhn's algorithm using digits array
int
luhn(long z)
{
    char digits[16] = { 0 };

    // get check digit and remove from "payload"
    int check_expected = z % 10;
    z /= 10;

    // split into digits (we use little-endian)
    int digcnt = 0;

    for (digcnt = 0; z != 0; ++digcnt, z /= 10)
        digits[digcnt] = z % 10;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int digidx = 0;  digidx < digcnt;  ++digidx) {
        int digcur = digits[digidx];

        if ((digidx & 1) == 0)
            sum += digsum(digcur * 2);
        else
            sum += digcur;
    }

    int check_actual = 10 - (sum % 10);

    return (check_actual == check_expected);
}

// luhn -- luhn's algorithm using long directly
int
luhn2(long z)
{

    // get check digit and remove from "payload"
    int check_expected = z % 10;
    z /= 10;

    int sum = 0;

    for (int digidx = 0;  z != 0;  ++digidx, z /= 10) {
        int digcur = z % 10;

        if ((digidx & 1) == 0)
            sum += digsum(digcur * 2);
        else
            sum += digcur;
    }

    int check_actual = 10 - (sum % 10);

    return (check_actual == check_expected);
}
```

Comment: no if you look at my Luhn equation, i take (sumall - sumodd) which should give me sumeven, which i multiplied with 2, then i add the sumodd. the equation can't be wrong imo. it's a coding issue.

Comment: @DanNguyen But the code you have is (All-Odd) *2 + All not (All-Odd)*2+*Odd*.

Comment: oh yes, but still even if i changed it to a sumodd it gives the wrong answer

Comment: @DanNguyen That's because you haven't initialised your variables. As per my answer it works according to your definition if you initialise the variables and do a `()%10` on the whole expression.
NB: I see you've edited the question to use `sumodd()` now. But you don't need to call it twice.

Answer (score 0):

You've invoked undefined behavior by not initializing a few local variables in your functions, for instance you can remove your undefined behaviour in `sumodd()` by initializing `a` to zero like so:

```
//sum of digits in odd position starting from the end
int sumodd(long x)
{
    int a = 0; //Initialize
    while(x)
    {
        a += x % 10; //You can "a += b" instead of "a = a + b"
        x /= 100;
    }
    return a;
}
```

It's also important to note that `long` is only required to be a minimum of 4-bytes wide, so it is not guaranteed to be wide enough to represent a decimal-16-digit-integer. Using `long long` solves this problem.

Alternatively you may find this problem much easier to solve by treating your credit card number as a `char[]` instead of an integer type altogether, for instance if we assume a 16-digit credit card number:

```
int luhn(long long z){

  char number[16]; //Convert CC number to array of digits and store them here

  for(int c = 0; c < 16; ++c){ 
    number[c] = z % 10; //Last digit is at number[0], first digit is at number[15]
    z /= 10;
  }

  int sum = 0;
  for(int c = 0; c < 16; c += 2){
    sum += number[c] + number[c + 1] * 2; //Sum the even digits and the doubled odd digits
  }

  return sum;
}
```

...and you could skip the `long long` to `char[]` translation part altogether if you treat the credit card number as an array of digits in the whole program

Answer (score 0):

This expression:

```
(sumall(z)-sumodd(z)) * 2 + sumall(z);
```

Should be:

```
((sumall(z)-sumodd(z)) * 2 + sumodd(z))%10;
```

Based on your own definition.

But how about:

```
(sumall(z) * 2 - sumodd(z))%10
```

If you're trying to be smart and base off `sumall()`. You don't need to call anything twice.

Also you don't initialise your local variables. You must assign variables values before using them in C.

Also you don't need the local variable `c` in the `luhn()` function. It's harmless but unnecessary.

As others mention in a real-world application we can't recommend enough that such 'codes' are held in a character array. The amount of grief caused by people using integer types to represent digit sequence 'codes' and identifiers is vast. Unless a variable represents a numerical quantity of something, don't represent it as an arithmetic type. More issue has been caused in my career by that error than people trying to use `double` to represent monetary amounts.

```
#include <stdio.h>


//sum of digits in odd position starting from the end
int sumodd(long x)
{
    int a=0;
    while(x)
    {
        a = a + x % 10;
        x /= 100;
    }
    return a;
}

//sum of all digits
int sumall(long y)
{
    int b=0;
    while(y)
    {
        b = b + y % 10;
        y /= 10;
    }
    return b;
}

//Luhn's Algorithm
int luhn(long z)
{
    return (sumall(z)*2-sumodd(z))%10;
}

int check_luhn(long y,int expect){
    int result=luhn(y);
    if(result==expect){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int check_sumodd(long y,int expect){
    int result=sumodd(y);
    if(result==expect){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int check_sumall(long y,int expect){
    int result=sumall(y);
    if(result==expect){
        return 0;
    }
    return 1;
}

int main(void) {
    int errors=0;
    errors+=check_sumall(1,1);
    errors+=check_sumall(12,3);
    errors+=check_sumall(123456789L,45);
    errors+=check_sumall(4273391,4+2+7+3+3+9+1);
    
    errors+=check_sumodd(1,1);
    errors+=check_sumodd(91,1);
    errors+=check_sumodd(791,8);
    errors+=check_sumodd(1213191,1+1+1+1);
    errors+=check_sumodd(4273391,15);
    
    errors+=check_luhn(1234567890,((9+7+5+3+1)*2+(0+8+6+4+2))%10);
    errors+=check_luhn(9264567897,((9+7+5+6+9)*2+(7+8+6+4+2))%10);
    if(errors!=0){
        printf("*ERRORS*\n");
    }else{
        printf("Success\n");
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```